# ¿Cómo insertar una foto en un campo?

Tags: php, html5, phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un botón que abre una ventana modal, esa que está en la foto. Como pueden ver también hay un visualizador de la foto que busco. Lo que me gustaría que me ayudaran es a saber cómo mandar esa foto cuando hago clic en el botón verde del campo llamado "Foto" del usuario que está logueado. Ya hice lo de recoger el id de la url y mandarlo al modal.

Aquí les presento mi código PHP, el cual lo único que hace es mandar las fotos al lugar equivocado, en una carpeta. Yo la quiero (la foto) en el campo del usuario llamado "foto" según el id del usuario (el logueado). Además ese código PHPse supone que debe tener algo como "INSERT INTO".

**PHP**

```
  <?php

 include ('conexion.php');

 if (isset($_FILES["file"]))

 {

  $file = $_FILES["file"];

  $nombre = $file["name"];

  $tipo = $file["type"];

  $ruta_provisional = $file["tmp_name"];

  $size = $file["size"];

  $dimensiones = getimagesize($ruta_provisional);

 $width = $dimensiones[0];

   $height = $dimensiones[1];
  $carpeta = "imagenes/";

  if ($tipo != 'image/jpg' && $tipo != 'image/jpeg' && $tipo != 'image/png'
  && $tipo != 'image/gif')

  {

  echo "Error, el archivo no es una imagen";

  }

  else if ($size > 1024*1024)

   {

    echo "Error, el tamaño máximo permitido es un 1MB";

  }

  else if ($width > 1024 || $height > 900)

  {

    echo "Error la anchura y la altura maxima permitida es 900px";

  }

   else if($width < 60 || $height < 60)

   {

    echo "Error la anchura y la altura mínima permitida es 60px";

  }

  else

   {

    $src = $carpeta.$nombre;

    move_uploaded_file($ruta_provisional, $src);

    echo "<img src='$src'>";

     }

      }

      ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

En general hay dos enfoques

1. Guardar el url, o path fisico del directorio que contiene las fotos, para lo cual lo que necesitas es un texto.
2. Guardar el binario como campo, para esto necesitar trabajar con `BLOB's`. Aquí http://php.net/manual/en/function.fbsql-create-blob.php esta la documentación de `PHP` para eso.

Comment: y cual es el que sastiface lo que quiero?Porque simplemente no quiero guardar una foto,sino que esa foto sea de ese usuario y solo de ese.

Answer (score 0):

La opción 1 es mas facil de implementar...simplemente guardas la foto en alguna carpeta designada para eso...(usualmente se renombra con el id del usuario) y guardas la dirección en tu tabla.... el problema de esto es que si deseas migrar tu sistema a otro lugar, debes recordar tambien mover esa carpeta....

Con La opción 2 al mirgrar tu base de datos migras todo incluido.